# Django models dependencies and transfer ownership

Tags: django, model, relationship

What I am trying to build is a app that can deal with honey production management.
There are number of producers that produce honey pots and they can give their pots to a variety of stores that have their customers. One producer can give his production to many stores, and a store can have honey pots from many producers. Honey pots can be tracked by pot_id. The models.py looks like this:

```
class Produser(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    produser= models.ManyToManyField(Produser)

class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    store = = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class HoneyPot(models.Model):
    produced_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    pot_id = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False)
    produser= models.ForeignKey(Produser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    store= models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'm struggling to find how to modify the models in the way that one pot to be owned or by producer or a shop or a customer. As right now when a new pot is created store and customers are required fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say that `Produser`, `Store` and `Customer` all have something in common, i.e. they can own a `HoneyPot`. Meaning they are specializations of let's say an entity that can own a `HoneyPot`. To model this we would simply add an extra model which `Produser`, `Store` and `Customer` all will either inherit from or have a one to one relationship with.

#### Using a [`OneToOneField` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/#one-to-one-relationships):

We can simply make the relationship by using a `OneToOneField`:

```
class HoneyPotOwner(models.Model):
    PRODUCER = 'P'
    STORE = 'S'
    CONSUMER = 'C'
    TYPE_CHOICES = [
        (PRODUCER, 'Producer'),
        (STORE, 'Store'),
        (CONSUMER, 'Consumer'),
    ]
    owner_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)

class Produser(models.Model):
    honey_pot_owner = models.OneToOneField(HoneyPotOwner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class Store(models.Model):
    honey_pot_owner = models.OneToOneField(HoneyPotOwner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class Customer(models.Model):
    honey_pot_owner = models.OneToOneField(HoneyPotOwner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class HoneyPot(models.Model):
    produced_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    pot_id = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(HoneyPotOwner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

#### Using [Multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance):

We can have `Produser`, `Store` and `Customer` inherit from `HoneyPotOwner` this is called **Multi-table inheritance**. This implicitly makes the `OneToOneField`, but has a few advantage that accessing the related fields becomes a little easier:

```
class HoneyPotOwner(models.Model):
    PRODUCER = 'P'
    STORE = 'S'
    CONSUMER = 'C'
    TYPE_CHOICES = [
        (PRODUCER, 'Producer'),
        (STORE, 'Store'),
        (CONSUMER, 'Consumer'),
    ]
    owner_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)

class Produser(HoneyPotOwner):
    ...

class Store(HoneyPotOwner):
    ...

class Customer(HoneyPotOwner):
    ...

class HoneyPot(models.Model):
    produced_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    pot_id = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(HoneyPotOwner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Huge Thanks! I wasn't familiar with this kind of sorcery :)