# django and postgres what is the alternative to uuid

Tags: python, django, postgresql, database-design

I want all of the ID fields of all model classes(tables) in my Django project to be unique. by unique I mean unique throughout all of the tables, not just one table.
I don't wanna use UUID due to the performance and storage issues and actually I don't need my Id fields to be that kind of unique I just want them to be probably a 5 or 6 digit unique number in 30 tables.
my database is Postgres.

Why I need it:
assume that there are 3 tables: news, article, and tag. I want to assign multiple tags to news or articles. so I store **tag_id** and news_id **or** article_id in another table called **typetag**.
so news and articles can not have similar ids as the django auto-incrementing primary key generates.
how would I tackle this problem?

Comment: An extra model which your models have a one to one field with? Or use the [The contenttypes framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/)? (You honestly don't need a pk unique over tables)

Comment: This approach might work coming from the article or news item, it doesn't work the other way coming from the tag, since you don't know what that id refers to, an article or a news item. You should simply store the type of the related item, e.g. `type: 'news', id: 42`. That's a proper polymorphic relationship, and then this question becomes moot.

Comment: It would be better to change the data model so that you have regular foreign key relationships between tables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django models dependencies and transfer ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66587561/django-models-dependencies-and-transfer-ownership) Note: I don't discuss the contenttypes framework there, but it too is a viable option.

Comment: yes I can solve the problem by changing the design but the approach you are suggesting is (i think)against normalization(making an extra table for every relation between for example tag and news)@LaurenzAlbe

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can be easily done by using relational databases (models) in django.

We have `ManyToOne` or `ForeignKey` which connects multiple rows of one table with another table.

we have `OneToOne` which connects a particular row of one table with another.

And lastly, which will help you is `ManyToMany` where we can join multiple rows of one table with multiple rows of another table.

`ManyToMany` atomatically creates an extra table in the database which shows the relation.

Check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/) for more details.

Comment: I'm familiar with entity relations :). when you are gonna have more than a hundred thousand records you should think about how I'm gonna query this data and what data I'm gonna be needing and at the same time design the database as normalized as possible. a lot of things can be done with entity relations but a few of them are the right choices.

Answer (score 0):

If you will be having limited number of tables and rows, you can set a unique starting value for each table by altering primary key sequence.

For example, assume you have 3 tables and each will be having at most 1m rows in future. You can set a starting value of the sequence of the first table to 1, second table to 1m and third table to 2m like that. if you will be having more than 1m rows, just increase it accordingly to be on the safe side.

You can change the starting value of sequence easily from psql terminal or pgadmin.

```
    alter sequence seq_name restart with 1;
```

Comment: Yes, your question was about Django only no!

Just install pg_admin software and find the sequence name there. if you don't know about the sequences, you can find more information from Google.

Comment: I know the database stuff, if I create this sequence just on the database side there is high chance that django core functionality will have conflicts with database and beside that defining a sequence on the database side is not in django best practices

Comment: You won't face such issues. For details, check this page. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757235/how-can-my-model-primary-key-start-with-a-specific-number